How to find the volume of a tetrahedron that isn't aligned with flat planes with triple integrals
Hi I'm having a lot of trouble solving this math problem, I have been working on it for about 3 hours (please help). I'm learning about triple integrals and I have no idea how to solve the volume of a tetrahedron that isn't laying flat on a plane.
The tetrahedron's volume I'm solving for is one with vertices: (-1,-1,1), (1,1,1), (1,-1,-1), and (-1,1,-1).
The problem states: evaluate the triple integral $\int\int\int5dxdydz$, where T is the tetrahedron shown in the following picture:
Provided picture
I know the planes I have to include in this are $x+y+z=-1$, $-x+y-z=-1$, $-x-y+z=-1$, $x-y-z=-1$, but clearly I'm not using them to set the bounds properly, because I submitted $\frac{80}{3}$ as my first answer and $40$ as my second answer and both are incorrect. Could someone help me with how to set the bounds for this triple integral? Thank you so so much in advance.

Do you know / can you use subsitution of multiple variables with the Jacobian determinant?

I have no clue how to do that, my professor didn't teach that

To reduce the bounds to two dimensions, we'll project everything onto a standard coordinate plane. Since this solid is so symmetric, it doesn't really matter which, so let's use the $xy$-plane: project each point $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,y)$. Then the vertices project to $(-1,-1), (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1)$. The tetrahedron's six edges project to the line segments between each pair of these: a square and its two diagonals.
The diagonal $(-1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$ divides the square region into two subregions: If $x-y \geq 0$, then the tetrahedron's maximum $z$ is on the plane $-x+y+z=-1$; if $x-y \leq 0$, then the maximum $z$ is on the plane $x-y+z=-1$. Similarly, the diagonal $(1,-1)$ to $(-1,1)$ divides the square region into two subregions: If $x+y \geq 0$, then the minimum $z$ is on the plane $-x-y+z=-1$; if $x+y \leq 0$, then the minimum $z$ is on the plane $x+y+z=-1$.
So the total triple integral is the sum of the triple integrals above and below each of four subregions of the $xy$-plane square. Each subregion has a specific plane for its minimum $z$ and another plane for its maximum $z$.
But rather than do these four integrals, notice they all have the same shape, because of the tetrahedron, and the integrand $5$ has the same values in each subregion. So we can do one triple integral and multiply it by $4$. (For this shortcut, both the regions of integration and the integrand formula must be symmetric! Otherwise, we may really need to integrate each subregion separately and add them.)
One of these subregions projected onto the $xy$-plane is the triangular region $S$, where $x+y \geq 0$, $x-y \geq 0$, and $x\leq 2$.
$$ \iiint_T 5\, dx\, dy\, dz = 4 \iint_S \int_{z_\textrm{min}}^{z_\textrm{max}} 5\, dz\, dx\, dy $$
Can you take it from here?

Yes, this definitely helped me visualize how to do it better! However, I ended up plugging in $4 \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-y}^{y} \int_{x+y-1}^{x-y-1} 5, dz, dx, dy$ and after doing all my math I got $4\frac{-20}{3}$ and that's $-\frac{80}{3}$ so I still got the same answer. However I went to my professor's office hours and he did $4 \int_{-1}{1} \int_{-z}{z} \int_{y+z-1}^{y-z+1} 5, dx, dy, dz$, it worked and he got $\frac{40}{3}$, I'm just kind of confused how he got the bounds and why mine was wrong?

Your maximum $z$ is at $z=x-y-1$, which is not one of the planes. The professor projected onto the $yz$-plane to do the integration with respect to $x$ first like the original $dx, dy, dz$ suggests. But since the thing is symmetric, notice your triple integral is related to the professors by just switching the variables around, except for one sign error.

Thank you so much for your help, it really helped me study for my quiz!
